# Write pattern to excel cell from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, design-patterns, vba

I recorded a Macro in excel to add a pattern to an excel cell. Following is what I get, however when I try to implement this code in VB.NET it is not accepting it. My understanding of VB.NET = Beginner/Intermediate

```
oSt2.Cells(20,i).Select()
oSt2.Cells(21,i).Select()
With Selection.Interior
 .Pattern = xlSolid
 .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
 .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
 .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
 .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Am i missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those code are VBA, not VB.NET, if you want to dig deeper, here's some information to help you convert from VBA to VB.net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192490%28v=office.11%29.aspx.

It is not difficult, trust me. VB.net is a cool language.